# SPRESENSEをArduinoIDEで開発しています。 GPS受信でFixするまでに時間がかかり低消費電力が出来ません。GPS受信確定を早くする方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: spresense

現在 SPRESENSE(CXD5602)上のGPS情報取得プログラムをArduinoIDEで作成しています。
電池駆動を目指しており、低消費電力化を測っております。（GPSははじめてです。）

その際、GPSの受信間隔を長くしたり※受信回数を変えていますが、Fixさせるまでに時間がかかります。
※Gnss.waitUpdate()を呼び出してUpdateしているとデータを受信していますが、waitUpdate()を
呼び出す時間間隔を変えています。

一度Fixすると、外れることはなかなかありませんが、Fixするまでに時間がかかりこの時に電流を消費してしまいます。

質問
１．複数の衛星情報を受信してFixまでの時間を早くする為にすべきことがあれば教えて下さい。
２．waitUpdate()を呼び出す時間はどの程度が最適なのでしょうか？

GPSやLowPower化は、下記を参考にしています。
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_developer_guide_ja.html#_gnss_%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA

Comment: 何か貴方の実際に行ったことの具体的な情報・ソースコードとか計量できる指標・数値・結果と言ったものを提示した方が良いでしょう。SPRESENSEサポート担当の人が答えるにしても、そうした情報を求められると思うので冗長なやり取りを増やすよりも先に提示しておけば時間が短縮できるでしょう。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に質問を改善してみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: 「早い/遅い」は感覚的な表現に過ぎないので、具体的な数値を上げたほうがよいと思います。

Comment: 私の認識違いでした。余分なdelay()で遅くしていました。
setup()で、waitUpdate()の時間設定を、Gnss.setInterval(XXXXX);にて実施できました。
【自己解決】
void loop() {
　if (Gnss.waitUpdate(-1)){← SetUpで待機時間を設定。
   }
   delay(XX);    ← このdelayが余分な待機時間。
}

Answer (score 0):

運営の方のご指摘のとおり、情報不足のため回答になっているかどうか分かりませんが、SPRESENSEでGPSのホットスタートを試したことがあるので、そのコードを掲載します。私もGPSに詳しいわけではないので、コードの内容については保証できません。やってみたらできた程度の内容なので、ご参考程度にしてください。

```
#include <GPS.h>
#include <LowPower.h>
#include <RTC.h>

static SpGnss Gnss;

void setup() {
  int resut;
  
  Serial.begin(115200);
  RTC.begin();

  LowPower.begin();
  LowPower.clockMode(CLOCK_MODE_32MHz);
  bootcause_e bc = LowPower.bootCause(); /* get boot cause */

  sleep(3);  
  Gnss.begin();
  Gnss.select(GPS); 
  Gnss.select(GLONASS); 
  Gnss.select(QZ_L1CA); 
  Gnss.select(QZ_L1S);
  
  if ((bc == POR_SUPPLY) || (bc == POR_NORMAL)) {
    Serial.println("Power on reset");
    Gnss.start(COLD_START);
  } else {
    Serial.println("Wakeup from deep sleep");
    RtcTime now = RTC.getTime();
    // Print the current clock
    printf("%04d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n",
           now.year(), now.month(), now.day(),
           now.hour(), now.minute(), now.second());

    SpGnssTime gnss_time;
    gnss_time.year = now.year();
    gnss_time.month = now.month();
    gnss_time.day = now.day();
    gnss_time.hour = now.hour();
    gnss_time.minute = now.minute();
    gnss_time.sec = now.second();
    gnss_time.usec = now.nsec() / 1000;
    Gnss.setTime(&gnss_time);
    Gnss.start(HOT_START);
  }

}

void loop() {
  if (!Gnss.waitUpdate(-1)) return;

  SpNavData NavData;
  Gnss.getNavData(&NavData);
  
  /* print satellites count */
  Serial.print("numSat: " + String(NavData.numSatellites) + " ");

  /* update RTC time */
  RtcTime gps_time(NavData.time.year
                 , NavData.time.month
                 , NavData.time.day
                 , NavData.time.hour
                 , NavData.time.minute
                 , NavData.time.sec
                 , NavData.time.usec * 1000 /* RtcTime requires nsec */);

  Serial.print(String(gps_time.year())   + "/" 
             + String(gps_time.month())  + "/" 
             + String(gps_time.day())    + " "
             + String(gps_time.hour())   + ":"
             + String(gps_time.minute()) + ":"
             + String(gps_time.second()) + " ");

  /* When time is different more than 1 sec, update RTC time */
  if (abs(RTC.getTime() - gps_time) >= 1) {
    RTC.setTime(gps_time);
    Serial.print(" * Updated RTC time * ");
  }
  
  /* print position data */
  if (NavData.posFixMode == FixInvalid && NavData.posDataExist == 0) {
    Serial.print("No Position");
  } else {
    static int g_loop = 0;
    Serial.print("Lat=" + String(NavData.latitude, 6));
    Serial.print(", Lon=" + String(NavData.longitude, 6));
    
    unsigned long passed_time;
    Serial.println("");
    passed_time = millis();
    Serial.println("POSITION FIXED TIME: " + String(passed_time));

    if (g_loop > 10) {
      // Go to deep sleep for 60 seconds
      Gnss.saveEphemeris();
      Gnss.stop();
      Gnss.end();
      passed_time = millis();
      Serial.println("Go to deep sleep... " + String(passed_time));
      LowPower.deepSleep(60);
    }
    ++g_loop;
  }
  Serial.println("");
}
```

Comment: 参考のコードありがとうございます。
一度実行して比較してみます。
有難うございます。

Comment: 私の誤解で間違ったコードで動作させておりました。
忘れないためにも、ここに追記しておきます。

【間違い】
loop() {

Comment: 私の認識違いでした。余分なdelay()で遅くしていました。
コードとは別の問題がありました。
バッテリーコネクタから5V(乾電池2本(3V)をDC-DCコンバータで昇圧)を供給していましたが、多分 DC-DCコンバータのノイズによりGPSの受信が上手く行かなかった用です。乾電池3本(4.5V)を繋げば、GPSの受信が改善され、Fixしやすくなりました。